# react-admin authorization permissions

Tags: node.js, permissions, authorization, react-admin

I try to make authorization and permissions availlable with react-admin and a Node server:https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-mongoose-boilerplate

For react-admin there is an exemple of code: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authorization.html#configuring-the-auth-provider

```
// in src/authProvider.js
import decodeJwt from 'jwt-decode';

export default {
    login: ({ username, password }) => {
        const request = new Request('https://example.com/authenticate', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        });
        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(({ token }) => {
                const decodedToken = decodeJwt(token);
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                localStorage.setItem('permissions', decodedToken.permissions);
            });
    },
    logout: () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        localStorage.removeItem('permissions');
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    checkError: error => {
        // ...
    },
    checkAuth: () => {
        return localStorage.getItem('token') ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();
    },
    getPermissions: () => {
        const role = localStorage.getItem('permissions');
        return role ? Promise.resolve(role) : Promise.reject();
    }
};
```

But i don't understand how it work and on login the server return an user object like this:

```
{user: {id: "5e429d562910776587c567a2", email: "admin@test.com", firstname: "Ad", lastname: "Min",…},…}
tokens: {access: {,…}, refresh: {,…}}
access: {,…}
expires: "2020-03-03T06:45:10.851Z"
token: "eyJhbGciOi..."
refresh: {,…}
expires: "2020-04-02T06:15:10.851Z"
token: "eyJhbGciOi..."
user: {id: "5e429d562910776587c567a2", email: "admin@test.com", firstname: "Ad", lastname: "Min",…}
createdAt: "2020-02-11T12:25:58.760Z"
email: "admin@test.com"
firstname: "Ad"
id: "5e429d562910776587c567a2"
lastname: "Min"
role: "admin"
updatedAt: "2020-02-11T12:25:58.760Z"
```

There are already tokens and role and in the server, it seems to have a permission control:
role.js

```
const roles = ['user', 'admin'];

const roleRights = new Map();
roleRights.set(roles[0], []);
roleRights.set(roles[1], ['getUsers', 'manageUsers']);

module.exports = {
  roles,
  roleRights,
};
```

And the auth.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const httpStatus = require('http-status');
const AppError = require('../utils/AppError');
const { roleRights } = require('../config/roles');

const verifyCallback = (req, resolve, reject, requiredRights) => async (err, user, info) => {
  if (err || info || !user) {
    return reject(new AppError(httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 'Please authenticate'));
  }
  req.user = user;

  if (requiredRights.length) {
    const userRights = roleRights.get(user.role);
    const hasRequiredRights = requiredRights.every(requiredRight => userRights.includes(requiredRight));
    if (!hasRequiredRights && req.params.userId !== user.id) {
      return reject(new AppError(httpStatus.FORBIDDEN, 'Forbidden'));
    }
  }

  resolve();
};

const auth = (...requiredRights) => async (req, res, next) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: true }, verifyCallback(req, resolve, reject, requiredRights))(req, res, next);
  })
    .then(() => next())
    .catch(err => next(err));
};

module.exports = auth;
```

But how to get authorization and permission works from the react-admin?

Thanks & Regards

Ludo

Answer (score -2):

In react-admin there is a usePermissions() hook, which calls the authProvider.getPermissions() method on mount. This method return to you single string value like 'admin' or string array of permissions like ['admin','crm'...]. This strings are up to you how to set. In example below it's storing in localStorage, but in real life need to extract it from JWT token or retrieve it from backend.

```
  getPermissions: () => {
        const role = localStorage.getItem('permissions');
        return role ? Promise.resolve(role) : Promise.reject();
    }
```

```
import { usePermissions } from 'react-admin';
in function
const { permissions } = usePermissions();

return (
 { permissions == 'admin' &&
  <DashboardMenuItem primaryText="Dashboard" onClick={onMenuClick} sidebarIsOpen={open} />
 }
...
);
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.